# How to solve NoClassDefFoundError in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror

I know this question has been asked a hundred times but none of the solutions seems to solve my problem.

Execution fails at this line:

```
final ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
```

imports:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
```

I added the jar file in a **libs** directory in the project, and to the project's libraries:

[image: libs]
[image: libraries]

I also tried checking it at **Order and Export**:

[image: OrderAndExport]

Then I started getting another error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: javax/script/ScriptEngineManager
```

Then tried removing **google-play-sevices.jar** from **Libraries** as some answer suggests, but i was still getting this error.

Comment: Are you using Maven? If yes, could you post the projects pom content? It could be you are importing a different version.

Comment: Where do you got the jar223-api.jar file?

Comment: @NicoMüller I don't even know what Maven is... (Apache?) I just need to execute javascript code from within java. So i'm using javax.script package

Comment: @kucing_terbang From here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsr223apijar.htm

Comment: Can you tell us which JDK you are using?

Comment: @AlaaM. can you try use the jar from this [site](https://code.google.com/p/jav8/) and tell us what the result?

Comment: @kucing_terbang Worked! (with the combination of checking it at **Order and Export**). Thanks